# Is it possible to bind Domination/ÜberCharge lines or not?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Is it possible to bind Domination/ÜberCharge lines to a specific key? Usually domination lines are only played when you are domination someone (clearly), but I'd like to bind them to a key.

I'm not sure if this is possible, because I'm pretty sure that the lines can only be activated by events though.

Related:

- [Voice Commands](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Voice_commands)
- [Response](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Responses)
- [Audio Cues](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Audio_cues)

Comment: You can definitely do it with admin plug-ins, but I don't think its  possible otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

If i understand your question you want to bind a specific phrase from the voice menu to a certain key using the command console. You can do that in this way:

e.g. `Need Dispenser` = `bind <key> "voicemenu 1 4"`

e.g. `Thanks!` = `bind <key> "voicemenu 0 1"`

But you can't single out a single type of response from the selection.

e.g. You can't choose between `Thanks!` or `Thank you!` when using the command mentioned above.

It may be possible to do this with a script though but from what i know it would still generate some kind of a random response.

In `Left 4 Dead` it was possible to select a certain response from the list.

EDIT: You can't bind the voice responses triggered by events to a key, only those from the voice menu.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't do this at all with Domination lines (the line a character says when he's dominating someone), because those are event-specific lines.  Similarly, I assume when you say "ubercharge line", you mean the line for when an ubercharge is activated/active, rather than the line for when you want to inform someone of a fully-charged uber.  This too is not possible, because it is an event-driven line.

Without some kind of server-side plug-in, these lines are only spoken during the key event.  There might also be certain plug-ins you can do to activate the specific line on your side, but no one else on the server would hear it/it wouldn't affect their computer.